# break a word in letters php

Tags: php

I want to accept a string from a form and then break it into an array of characters using PHP, for example:

```
$a = 'professor';
$b[0] == 'p';
$b[1] == 'r';
$b[2] == 'o';
.
.
.
.
.
$b[8] = 'r';
```

Comment: You know that strings in php are defined by " or ' ? ;)

Comment: Hey, I saw your profile and I can see you didn't mark any answer as correct for any of the questions you made. When you find your solution, you should mark that as the correct answer for your question. That will help anyone coming here with the same problem to see what the solution actually is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't need to do that. In PHP you can access your characters directly from the string as if it where an array:

```
$var = "My String";
echo $var[1]; // Will print "y".
```

Comment: FYI, $var{1} will work, but it's being deprecated as of PHP6 in favor of $var[1].

Answer (score 9):

```
str_split($word);
```

<del>This is faster than accessing $word as an array.</del> (And also better in that you can iterate through it with `foreach()`.) [Documentation](https://www.php.net/str_split).

Comment: Why is it faster?  It just returns an array.

Comment: It is not faster; in fact, it's slower - it has to create an additional array and see where to split the original string depending on the second parameter.

Comment: You're correct: a benchmark confirms that this is 50% slower than your method.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want the individual characters in a variable of array type, as opposed to just needing to access the character by index, use:

```
$b = str_split($a)
```

Otherwise, just use $a[0], $a[1], etc...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful because the examples above only work if you are treating ASCII (single byte) strings.